# IN.User is undefined in LinkedIn Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying to log the user in programatically using LinkedIn Javascript SDK. I am not using the default flow (which includes the button as a script) as we need a custom size button, so here is my code:

```
//inside head...
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    credentials_cookie: true
</script>

//inside some script tag
function loginWithLinkedIn() {
    IN.User.authorize(linkedInLoginCallback); //yeah I have that method
}
```

However, as soon as call `loginWithLinkedIn`, I'm getting an error telling `IN.User` is undefined. `IN` itself *is* defined, but has only `ENV` and `Event` fields defined. How can I initiate LinkedIn login using JS (not a button/script tag)? I couldn't find any useful documentation anywhere, and LinkedIn's own documentation is terrible.

Comment: did you ever figure out your issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @moesef at some point, yes, but I don't remember how the error went away. but I assure you the same function now works.

Comment: I answered with what resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. For me it was because we had changed the subdomain location of our application from www. to app. This change required me to go into the LinkedIn developer console and under the `Javascript` tab add our new app location to the list of Valid SDK Domains.